# String a Entero utilizando atoi en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy realizando un programa que convierta un numero en `string` a `entero`, he utilizado la función `atoi` que viene en `<stdlib.h>` pero me sale el siguiente error:

> [Error] cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int atoi(const char*)'

La entrada la obtengo mediante un `.txt:`

```
V20483031154 50
U64329085364 50
V20487646102 50
```

- **Código:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void archivo()
{
    ifstream archivo;
    int d = 0;
    int numero;
    string s;
    char a;

    archivo.open("Entrada.txt", ios::in);

    if(archivo.fail())
    {
         cout<<"Ocurrio un error con el archivo."<<endl;
         exit(1);
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {

        archivo >> a >> s >> d;

        numero = atoi(s);

        cout<< a <<" "<< numero <<" "<< d <<endl;
    }


    archivo.close();
}

int main()
{

    archivo();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Lo que necesito es que la variable `s` que es un `string`, se pase a `entero`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String es una clase, por lo tanto tiene la dirección base del objeto instanciado. Entonces no es posible pasar esa dirección como argumento en la función atoi (su parámetro espera una variable de tipo char*).
Por esa razón, debes usar el método c_str, debido a que, retorna un puntero de tipo const char*.
Ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "1222";
    const char * b = a.c_str();
    int x = atoi(b);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Puedes pasar `a.c_str()` directamente a `atoi`. O mejor aún: dejar de usar herramientas de [tag:c] y usar herramientas de [tag:c++] como [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars).